# How to duplicate and show a specific row in new address in excel 2007

Tags: excel

I use excel 2007
i made a table with few columns but too many rows. Each row contains some data and simple formulas.Now I want to duplicate a specific row based on current date [TODAY()] at top of the sheet.I mean whenever I open the file,the right row according to computer date,be shown directly at somewhere else instead of looking through all rows to find it.
thanks

Comment: I'm not completely clear, but to clarify. You have a list of dates and other such data. When excel opens you want to copy the data in the row belonging to todays date to a blank row at the top of the sheet?

Comment: YA YA U HIT THE GOAL EXACTLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above your table. add an empty row.

First column add =TODAY() // This will show todays date in the column and can be used in your other formulas. We will assume the cell is A1

Second Column add = VLOOKUP($A$1,A2:D8,2,FALSE) A1 being the date, A2:D8 being the table range (A2 top left cell, D8 bottom right cell), 2 is the second column of your table range, false returns the value in the second column as longs as the date (A1) matches the date in the first column on your table range.

Copy the formaula across the columns, changing the lookup column in the formula. ie. Third column VLOOKUP($A$1,A2:D8,3,FALSE)

Glad to help.

Comment: Hi Rob I should thank you for your help.It solved my problem.

Comment: Have any idea about this? (How to send a specific excel data as a pop up message on desktop by these rules:

1- Auto pop up at start up 2- By user click
3- contents data varies based on computer current date.

Does anybody know How? 

Thanks ) I think i should use Excel VBA and tried some,but wasnt successful.